# Configure silverlight and flash to play though different sound devices

Tags: audio, flash, silverlight

I have a multi-monitor setup I use at home for TV where my wife is watching mainly
YouTube. I would like to watch Netflix at the same time, but have the sound output to headphones for Netflix.

Currently I have to download whatever I will watch and view through VLC player, which
does let me what sound device I want.

I am wondering if there is anyway I can setup flash for YouTube and Silverlight
 to use different sound devices, or another way to direct the sound for each to different sound devices?

I would rather not have to download many episodes of a YouTube playlist to play both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and even considering buying a second computer, I found a way to do what I wanted.

I set up a Virtual Machine using VMware-player and installed Ubuntu.

I can watch my YouTube, Netflix or Hulu  in one screen with audio in my headphones 
while my wife can watch her YouTube through ubuntu on the other screen with audio though speakers.

I did try VirtualBox first but that had the same problem of not being able to select the sound card for audio unless it was selected as windows default.

VMware-player was able to do what I needed though.